# Meaning of field d_off in last struct dirent

Tags: c, linux, unix

man getdensts says that in d_off an offset to next struct dirent is kept. But what should be kept in this field for last dirent? I was unable to find this SVr4 standard to look there, but man says nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"SVr4" means [Unix System V Release 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V#SVR4). Solaris is based on that, and [Solaris says](http://www.shrubbery.net/solaris9ab/SUNWaman/hman3head/dirent.3head.html):

> The `d_off` entry contains a value which is interpretable only by the filesystem that generated it. It may be supplied as an offset to `lseek(2)` to find the entry following the current one in a directory.

If you look at the [example in the Linux manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html#EXAMPLE), you'll find a program that uses `getdents`. It doesn't rely on the `d_off` of the final entry, which is apparently indeterminate, but on the return value from `getdents`, to determine how many entries there are.

Btw., the Linux manpage also states quite clearly that you shouldn't be using the `getdents` system call and that it isn't even supported by GLibc. Use the POSIX `readdir` interface instead.

Comment: The problem for me is that I wrote my own readdir and I dont't know what should I put is last direntry. So I put the same what linux kernel puts, but I was not sure if it is regulated by some standard. And the Linux kernel puts there offset in the directory, what could be used for further calls.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's `0`, which could not indicate any next entry as the value implicitly needs to be larger `0` and also wouldn't be wrong as it points to a valid entry, namely the first one.